# How to specify search field in AWS CloudSearch (using .net SDK)

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

I have a domain where I have 2 searchable fields (a literal and a text field), basically Category and Content.

How can I specify a specific field to use in a field? From what I can tell, it will default to search all searchable fields, but that is not what I want (ie, don't want to look for category Cats and get a result from another category just because it includes the word Cat in the content.)

I am using .Net SDK, and I've been going through their documentation, but can't find that section.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging a bit more, and that the way to specify a field is using the `fields` array field.

When using the `.Net SDK`, it can be done this way:

```
new SearchRequest { 
   Query = query, 
   QueryOptions = @"{""fields"":[""field_name""]}" 
};
```

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/search-api.html#structured-search-syntax

Comment: Have you worked on cloud search.i am looking for java or c# cloud search code.can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

Sample codes for Cloudsearch in C# aren't common however you can try this one i wrote

```
public List<AdditionalFields> Search(string query)
    {
        var batch = new List<AdditionalFields>();
        query = query.Trim();
        try
        {
            // Configure the Client that you'll use to make search requests
            string queryUrl = @"http://search-********.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com";
            var awsCredentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials();
            AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient searchClient = new AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient(queryUrl, awsCredentials);

            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
            searchRequest.Query = query;
            //searchRequest.Facet =
            //searchRequest.QueryOptions.
            searchRequest.Return = "_all_fields";

            SearchResponse searchResponse = searchClient.SearchAsync(searchRequest).Result;

            foreach (var hit in searchResponse.Hits.Hit)
            {
                var fields = new AdditionalFields();
                var searchfields = new Fields();
                searchfields.content = hit.Fields["content"][0].ToString();
                searchfields.directory = hit.Fields["directory"][0].ToString();
                searchfields.resourcename = hit.Fields["resourcename"][0].ToString();
                searchfields.title = hit.Fields["title"][0].ToString();
                fields.abridgedContent = searchfields.content.Replace(searchfields.title, string.Empty);
                searchfields.version = hit.Fields["version"][0].ToString();
                fields.abridgedContent = Abridged(fields.abridgedContent, query);
                searchfields.description = hit.Fields["description"][0].ToString();
                searchfields.resourcename = hit.Fields["resourcename"][0].ToString();
                searchfields.resourcetype = hit.Fields["resourcetype"][0].ToString();
                fields.url = "/bookviewer?bookValue=" + searchfields.resourcename + "&version=" + searchfields.version + "&chapterFolder=" + searchfields.directory + "&firstChapterNo=" + searchfields.description + ".htm";
                fields.fields = searchfields;
                batch.Add(fields);
            }

            // return searchResponse.Status.ToString();
        }
        catch (AmazonCloudSearchDomainException ex)
        {
            var fields = new AdditionalFields();
            fields.error = "ERROR : " + ex.Message;

            batch.Add(fields);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var fields = new AdditionalFields();
            fields.error = "ERROR : " + ex.Message;
            batch.Add(fields);
        }

        return batch;
    }
```

Comment: u should install the cloudsearchdomain nuget package